# Zoom Out by reversing Zoom In Mouse

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, zooming, mouseevent

I have a block of code which is executed on a C# Windows Form upon Mouse_Up. It basically zooms in on a rendered image and keeps zooming in each time the rubber band is drawn. I want to reverse this by adding a checkbox (which I have already done) and if the check box is ticked, do zooming out instead from the current view as per drawing of the rubber band. I thought it would be as simple as using the opposite operands i.e "+" instead of a "-" but it won't work. I have posted the event code below. There is a conditional IF on there for changing of the checkbox state. The first lot work fine with zooming in. The section after the ELSE IF doesn't let me zoom out - hence I have just left repeated code there for someone to look at. Thanks

```
private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked == false)
        {
            int z, w;
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            // Set internal flag to know we no longer "have the mouse".
            weHaveMouse = false;
            // If we have drawn previously, draw again in that spot
            // to remove the lines.
            if (ptLast.X != -1)
            {
                toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Please click and drag to zoom into the Fractal";
                Point ptCurrent = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
                MyDrawReversibleRectangle(ptOriginal, ptLast);
            }
            // Set flags to know that there is no "previous" line to reverse.
            ptLast.X = -1;
            ptLast.Y = -1;
            ptOriginal.X = -1;
            ptOriginal.Y = -1;
            //e.consume();
            if (action)
            {
                xe = e.X;
                ye = e.Y;
                if (xs > xe)
                {
                    z = xs;
                    xs = xe;
                    xe = z;
                }
                if (ys > ye)
                {
                    z = ys;
                    ys = ye;
                    ye = z;
                }
                w = (xe - xs);
                z = (ye - ys);
                if ((w < 2) && (z < 2)) initvalues();
                else
                {
                    if (((float)w > (float)z * xy)) ye = (int)((float)ys + (float)w / xy);
                    else xe = (int)((float)xs + (float)z * xy);
                    xende = xstart + xzoom * (double)xe;
                    yende = ystart + yzoom * (double)ye;
                    xstart += xzoom * (double)xs;
                    ystart += yzoom * (double)ys;
                }
                xzoom = (xende - xstart) /(double)x1;
                yzoom = (yende - ystart) / (double)y1;
                mandelbrot();
                rectangle = false;
                //Refresh();
            }
        }
        else if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            int z, w;
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            // Set internal flag to know we no longer "have the mouse".
            weHaveMouse = false;
            // If we have drawn previously, draw again in that spot
            // to remove the lines.
            if (ptLast.X != -1)
            {
                toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Please click and drag to zoom into the Fractal";
                Point ptCurrent = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
                MyDrawReversibleRectangle(ptOriginal, ptLast);
            }
            // Set flags to know that there is no "previous" line to reverse.
            ptLast.X = -1;
            ptLast.Y = -1;
            ptOriginal.X = -1;
            ptOriginal.Y = -1;
            //e.consume();
            if (action)
            {
                xe = e.X;
                ye = e.Y;
                if (xs > xe)
                {
                    z = xs;
                    xs = xe;
                    xe = z;
                }
                if (ys > ye)
                {
                    z = ys;
                    ys = ye;
                    ye = z;
                }
                w = (xe - xs);
                z = (ye - ys);
                if ((w < 2) && (z < 2)) initvalues();
                else
                {
                    if (((float)w > (float)z * xy)) ye = (int)((float)ys + (float)w / xy);
                    else xe = (int)((float)xs + (float)z * xy);
                    xende = xstart + xzoom * (double)xe;
                    yende = ystart + yzoom * (double)ye;
                    xstart += xzoom * (double)xs;
                    ystart += yzoom * (double)ys;
                }
                xzoom = (xende - xstart) / (double)x1;
                yzoom = (yende - ystart) / (double)y1;
                mandelbrot();
                rectangle = false;
                //Refresh();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in my humble opinion, there is no need to draw rubber band when you are zooming out. Just a click where the zoomed out image will be centered. Nevertheless, I cannot see the difference in the code you provided between the code for zooming in and zooming out. In general, the simplest thing to do is to zoom out the image in a way that current center of the image remains at its place and handle the image drawing in a way that X and Y coordinates are divided by 2 and Width and Height are multiplied by 2. 
In case of your code, calculating something like this at the end of code **could maybe** do the trick:

```
xzoom = 1/xzoom;
yzoom = 1/yzoom;
```